# swap a length of bits in 2 bytes

Tags: c, byte, swap

I would like to input 2 unsigned char variables:a and b. If use a(0) for bit 0 in a, I would like to swap a(6) to a(1) with b(6) to b(1). Finally I wish to get 2 new unsigned char_type variables:a1 and b1 with required bits swapped. I would love to know that is there method to address this issue in C language?

An further requirement is that add 2 variables: pa and pb to decide the start position for the length. For example: if pa=6, pb=7, I have to swap a(6) to a(1) with b(7) to b(2).

Any good solution?

Comment: You are going to have to give examples here. This question doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: I would like to input 2 unsigned char variable:a and b. If use a(0) for bit 0 in a, I would like to swap a(6) to a(1) with b(6) to b(1). Finally I wish to get 2 new char variable:a1 and b1 with required bits swapped.

Comment: Is there any possible method to solve this problem using C language？

Comment: You can (and should) edit the question

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan This is part of the homework. I am a little confused  now if the start position is not same for the 2 unsigned char variables. Any attempt for this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: I have marked it `homework` to reflect that. It will change how we try to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha. I get it now

```
unsigned const char mask = 0x3e;

usigned char a,b; // input somehow

unsigned char a2=a, b2=b;

a2 = (a2 & ~mask) | (b & mask);
b2 = (b2 & ~mask) | (a & mask);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be normal assignment?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer~I have added some further requirement with the question. Is there any solution?

Comment: @Xeo Oops. Late to spot your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'd be inclined to use xor masking:

```
mask = 0x3e;    // 0b00111110
diff = (a & mask) ^ (b & mask);
a1 = a ^ diff;
b1 = b ^ diff;
```

Answer (score 0):

Given integers, e.g.:

```
uint32_t a = 0xff00ff00;
uint32_t b = 0x00ff00ff;
```

This is how you swap entire values:

```
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

If you want to swap only specific bits, add a mask there:

```
uint32_t mask = 0x0000ffff; // only swap the lower 16 bits
a ^= (b & mask);
b ^= (a & mask);
a ^= (b & mask);
```

The above requires 6 bitwise operations, whereas [ecatmur's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12582841/412080) requires only 5.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. What I want to do is further more: the positions of bits to swap in 2 bytes are different. For example, uchar8 a=0xf0, uchar8 b=0x0f. I would like to swap bit7 and bit6 of a with bit1 and bit0 of b. Is there any method in C language to do so？

Comment: You would need to use shifts to do that. Just post another question.